# How to resize arrays in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I have to write a method that inserts an integer into an already sorted integer array and another that removes an integer from that array. Then I have to print out that same array. Is is possible to make an array one element longer or shorter in Java?

The code shown is the example from my homework.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] a1 = {-8,-5,-3,0, 3, 7, 10, 12,15, 22};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a1));
    addInt(a1, 2);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a1));
    addInt(a1, 13);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a1));
    removeInt(a1,-5);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a1));
    removeInt(a1, 10);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a1));
    System.out.print(getInt(a1, 2));    //should output 0
}
```

I've tried setting my new array to the original array, a1, in my addInt method but when I run it, it just prints out the unmodified array. I'm not allowed to use ArrayList.

Edit: Resolved. The assignment was made impossible on purpose as an exercise leading up to our introduction of ArrayList.

Comment: You can't resize arrays. You can create a new array with increased size and copy the old content into it...

Comment: If resizability is a requirement, then the array is the wrong tool for the job. Use ArrayList instead.

Answer (score 1):

Guessing you wrote `addInt` something like this:

```
void addInt(int[] a, int n){
    int[] newArray = new int[a.length+1];
    System.arraycopy(a, 0, newArray, 0, a.length);
    newArray[a.length] = n;
    a = newArray;        // WRONG!
}
```

Method parameters in Java are passed **by value**, which basically means that `a` in `addInt` and `a1` in the call `addInt(a1, 2)` are two separate variables. Upon entry into `addInt`, `a` initially refers to the same array as `a1` but beyond that there is no further relationship between `a` and `a1`, and subsequently changing `a` to refer to something else has no effect on `a1`.

Your only option is to change `addInt` so that it returns the new array as a function result:

```
int[] addInt(int[] a, int n){
    int[] newArray = new int[a.length+1];
    System.arraycopy(a, 0, newArray, 0, a.length);
    newArray[a.length] = n;
    return newArray;
}
```

and then call it like this:

```
a1 = addInt(a1, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify the  array length.
 when you create an array like int[] fixedLEngthArray = new int[n] you bassically reserved memory for n ints.
if you need n+1 wou will have to create a new array into which to copy the old one and insert/remove the element.